# How do I compute for the fields of matching documents in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my sample document:

```
{
    "jobID": "ace4c888-1907-4021-a808-4a816e99aa2e",
    "startTime": 1415255164835,
    "endTime": 1415255164898,
    "moduleCode": "STARTING_MODULE"
}
```

- I have thousands of documents.
- I have a pair of documents with the **same jobID** and the module code would be STARTING_MODULE and ENDING_MODULE.
- My formula would be ENDING_MODULE endTime minus STARTING_MODULE startTime equals the elapsed time it took the module to process.

My question is: **How do I get the total of all results with the elapsed time that is less than let's say 28800000?**

Is such results possible with Elasticsearch? I'd like to display my results in Kibana too.

Please let me know if this needs more clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, might not be ideal, but it returns a jobID and the elapsed time. First I'm assuming `jobID` and `moduleCode` are `not_analyzed`:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "jobs": {
      "properties": {
        "jobID":{
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "startTime":{
          "type": "date"
        },
        "endTime":{
          "type": "date"
        },
        "moduleCode":{
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Used [`scripted_metric` aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) available in ES 1.4.0 to compute the difference between those two values. Haven't looked into how to add the filtering for "less than 28800000", but I hope there can be something done with that script to limit this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "jobIds": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "jobID"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "executionTimes": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "_agg['time'] = 0L",
            "map_script": "if (doc['moduleCode'].value == \"STARTING_MODULE\") { _agg['time']=-1*doc['startTime'].value } else { _agg['time']=doc['endTime'].value}",
            "combine_script": "execution = 0; for (t in _agg.time) { execution += t };return execution",
            "reduce_script": "execution = 0; for (a in _aggs) { execution += a }; return execution"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the result should be something like this:

```
   "aggregations": {
      "jobIds": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "ace4c888-1907-4021-a808-4a816e99aa1e",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "executionTimes": {
                  "value": 1
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "ace4c888-1907-4021-a808-4a816e99aa2e",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "executionTimes": {
                  "value": 1000201063
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "ace4c888-1907-4021-a808-4a816e99aa3e",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "executionTimes": {
                  "value": 10000
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```